# How to make an ajax function to execute only in in a certain case?

Tags: javascript, django, ajax

I have an ajax function that updates every second some value on page, I want to update it only when the script is working, because to not request a value that is the same.

The script is updating this value, and ajax is refreshing it on website, but when script is not working, my ajax is requesting the value. How to make it work only when the script is working?

```
var interval = 1000;
function update() {
    $.ajax({
            type: 'GET',
            url: 'http://localhost:8000/api/updating',
            headers : {'Authorization': "Token "+ token,},
            data: $(this).serialize(),
            dataType: 'json',
            success: function (data) {
                $('#points_a').html(data)// first set the value
            },
            complete: function (data) {
                    // Schedule the next
                    setTimeout(update, interval);
            }
    });
}
setTimeout(update, interval);
```

This is script in python view, Django:

```
def task(userid, seconds_for_thirtydays=0):
    if(seconds_for_thirtydays < 2592000):
        p_a = Wallet.objects.filter(name__id=userid).values("points").first()['points']
        add = p_a + 1
        result = Wallet.objects.filter(name__id=userid).update(points=add)

        seconds_for_thirtydays = seconds_for_thirtydays + 1
        time.sleep(1)
        task(userid)
    else:
        return
```

The thing that I want to make is: When the value is not changing(the script is not working), then this ajax won't work and won't make requests, is it possible?

Comment: Why does the script not work sometimes? Seems like that's the real problem here.

Comment: @mykaf Under the words "is not working" I meant that for example when user pressed button => script activates and work for 30days => after it stops and the value is not updating, I don't want to work ajax at the same time

Comment: Can you set a flag when the script is inactivated and check that with your ajax first before updating?

Comment: @mykaf Maybe, is it possible with ajax, or I will just made this logic in python and with ajax just send request to script in order to verify it?

Comment: what you need to do and should use is called [clearInterval](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/clearInterval).

Comment: I'm not familiar with python or django. Could you return a value from the script when its inactive indicated that the ajax response shouldn't t update the screen?

Comment: As per the comments above, after enough time passed with the onClick event fired through this button, you should reset your interval above with the function I mentioned above.

Comment: @ErhanYaşar Understood, it kinda can help me, I will try this.

Comment: @mukaf thanks, this is also an option that I will check

Comment: @Fors1t try it other than introducing any other concepts since you also make use of `setInterval` with your codebase. setInterval keeps running forever unless it's stopped so that it's better to keep up with one full functionality instead of mixing couple concepts. And please let me know if that works in a way you want to implement or not.